# SCJP - exam question

Tags: java, scjp

It's actually from **SCJP 6 StudyGuide Exam310-065(MGH,2008)**
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1f37466409.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/1f37466409.png)
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/03aaff252a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/03aaff252a.png)
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b56385a448.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/b56385a448.png)
[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/83761fff86.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/83761fff86.png)

The call to *super()* in *Kinder* class constructor seems to be redundant because of:

- quote from the book:
  [alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8984096dc6.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/8984096dc6.png) 
  i.e. that there is no need to type super() explicitly, as this can be done by compiler
- the compiler accepts very well version without call to *super()*

---

The question is, if authors made some mistake in this question or am I missing something (more likely)

Comment: Is this really the kind of question the SCJP asks? If it is, then the SCJP is even more worthless than I imagined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I may be missing something (most likely), but it sounds like it's stated in the text:

a. The line cannot be left blank, as the parentheses are already in place.

That is, a constructor can be empty..  except that empty parentheses would be a syntax error (so it wouldn't compile).

b. Further, since the superclass constructor called is the no-argument version, this constructor must be created.

I think you may just have to re-read the text one more time and it should all click. Or I am really off on the whole thing.. in that case I apologize, it's kind of late over here. ;-)

Comment: a) constructor with empty body is not a syntax error. b) I have no objection that no-arg constructor should be created, my point was that super()-call is redundant

Comment: @kilonet: you are correct in both points, but they are not relevant to the question. Since the template already has the parenthesis in there without an argument, you need to put *something* there to make it valid Java code. That's the only reason for the no-args `super()` call there. It's a kind of trick question, in my opinion.